# ASP.NET core: NSwag vs. Swashbuckle

Tags: c#, .net, nswag, swashbuckle.aspnetcore

we're currently using **Swashbuckle.AspNetCore** for API documentation purpose, but when it comes to generation of client-side models (Typescript) it seems there is a major drawback of it.

As a sample, I enhanced the known ASP.NET default project (WeatherForecast) with a base class

```
public class InfoEntryBase    
{        
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class WeatherForecast : InfoEntryBase
{
   public DateTime Date { get; set; }

   public int TemperatureC { get; set; }

   public int TemperatureF => 32 + (int)(TemperatureC / 0.5556);

   public string Summary { get; set; }
}
```

It then exposes WeatherForecast as

```
WeatherForecast{
name    string
nullable: true
description string
nullable: true
date    string($date-time)
temperatureC    integer($int32)
temperatureF    integer($int32)
readOnly: true
summary string
nullable: true
}
```

and the inheritance gets lost.
This will make it impossible to auto-generate client-side models from the server-side code as we naturally like to port the inheritance to the Typescript code.

On investigating **NSwag.AspNetCore** I discovered it to take care about the inheritance. It exposes:

```
WeatherForecast{
name    string
description string
date*   string($date-time)
temperatureC*   integer($int32)
temperatureF*   integer($int32)
summary string
}
InfoEntryBase{
name    string
description string
}
```

Did I overlook something regarding Swashbuckle or is there no alternative to switch from it to NSwag?

You can review the code on
https://github.com/ClemensOesterle/NSwagSpike/tree/swashbuckle
whereas the NSwag implementation resides in the master branch.

Answer (score 8):

This solved it.

```
services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.UseAllOfForInheritance();
```